# (1/1) Swift_TransportException for reset password in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel project, When the user puts his email in the reset password form, this is displayed:

> Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
>   535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials 198sm71410981wmt.36 - gsmtp
>   "

.env file setting:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myusername@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Comment: make app password in gmail and used that. Google increase there security ,So you can't directly use your password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSL :

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=<your_email_address>
MAIL_PASSWORD=<your_gmail_app_password>
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

TLS :

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp    
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com   
MAIL_PORT=587      
MAIL_USERNAME=<your_email_address>
MAIL_PASSWORD=<your_gmail_app_password>
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Then run `php artisan config:cache`

For Gmail password use the App Password. [Generate App Password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en)

Check the **How to generate an App password** in given link.